# Xcode 4.3.2 unable to find its own include files

Tags: xcode, header

I am trying to build dtrace on Mac OS X 10.7.3 with Xcode 4.3.2. However, running xcodebuild gives me following errors.

~/dtrace-90/libelf/ar.c:34:16: error: ar.h: No such file or directory
~/dtrace-90/libelf/ar.c:35:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

**Why is xcodebuild failing to find it own standard header files?**

I have done: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I installed "Command Line Tools for Xcode" and things now work :-)